# Failed to start "Kofax" Management Console. Failed to start embedded Tomcat, check if port 50087 is already in use

Tags: rpa, kofax

Post installation of Kofax Kapow RPA tool, I am trying to start "Management Console". While starting, I am getting error as ***"Failed to start Management Console. Failed to start embedded Tomcat, check if port 50087 is already in use"***

I have tried command in my windows machine ***"netstat -p tcp -o -a -n"*** and tried to find if there is any application using ***"50087"*** port number. But, I could not any application using the mentioned port number.

Can anybody please let me know if there is anything else I need to change in configuration ?

***Please Note:*** 
I have even tried changing the port number in mc.config file to ***"44444"***. Port issue was resolved. But, started getting another errror ***" Failed to start Management Console. java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'scheduled' with classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6"***

Appreciate if anybody can help me identifying the issue.